# Get object represented by a proxy using java reflections

Tags: java, reflection, proxy

Lets say i have a Proxy to an object, can I somehow get access to the object via reflection or other technique ?

Comment: when you say a Proxy, you mean the pattern or some java class?

Comment: By proxy i mean the java class(technology) when you have a remote object and you can use it remotely via a proxy class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as a Proxy is not even itself a "true" object. From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), you can see that the only object you can easily access is the invocation handler. Once this handler is reached, it's a matter of implementation :

- you may encounter n invocation handler that keeps a reference to proxied object (as an example for kind of a decorator)
- but you can also have no other reference (as an example, when implementing the [Null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) using proxy).

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "Proxy to an object"? If you mean the invocation handler of a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` instance:

```
InvocationHandler handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(proxy);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proxy to an object you can use the proxy to access the object.

proxy - An interface for a service, especially for one that is remote, resource-intensive, or otherwise difficult to use directly. [(wiktionary)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proxy)